# jQuery Remove element where child is not

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am trying to hide all table rows where the anchor in that tr does not have an id of x.

I have got this, but it doesn't work, is it selected wrong or not possible this way?

```
<table><tr><td><a id="x">X</a></td></tr></table>
...
$("table tr:not(td a#x)").hide();
```

Thanks

Comment: From your question it looks like you're reusing the same id multiple times. That won't fly, even if we help you with the selector.

Comment: Use same class instead of id.

Comment: Using `:has` selector: `$("table tr").not(':has(#x)').hide();`

Comment: @undefined why didn't you make an asnwer? this is the easiest.

Comment: @undefined I agree, this is easier than my `filter` method.

Comment: I'll post an answer as an alternative.

Comment: Reworded the question to be singular, long day.
They are all unique, order numbers, @undefined's method works perfectly, please add and I'll mark as the answer. Thanks again

Comment: I have edited my answer to have an alternative to undefined method. I hope it's better now. Sorry but before I did not read well your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `not` method and `:has` selector:

```
$("table tr") // all `tr` elements
  .not(':has(#x)') // not having `#x` descendant
  .hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to change your `x` ID to a class. It's not possible to have more than 1 of the same ID on a page. But using classes you can use `filter` to get rid of results you don't want. `!$('td a', this).hasClass('x');` will find `td a` in the tr and check if it has the class. next it returns the opposite because you only want to hide `tr`s that do **not** have `a.x`.

```
$("table tr").filter(function(){
    return !$('td a', this).hasClass('x');
}).hide();
```

Comment: You should explain it to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

1) IDs cannot be reused more than one time on a single html page
2) Use classes instead

You can either use the CSS :not or the jQuery .not() as a selector.

Performance wise also proven by this [jsperf link](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not) the CSS :not selector is much faster.

```
$('table tr:not(:has(".x"))').hide();
```

The main selector selects all table tr using the CSS `:not` selector and then using the `:has` jQuery selector checks if any children element have the .x class. I suggest you to edit your html structure and do not use ids for this matter unless you have only one instance of them on a single html page.

This is a similar to the user 'underfined' answer but it is slightly faster.

I have created an example for you:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7ceRx/4/

In case you want to use it with IDs instead of classes:

```
 $('table tr:not(:has("#x"))').hide();
```

Comment: Ok, sorry I did not read the answer carefully. I will edit my answer with a different method.

Comment: Just posted, I hope it's better now. :)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use multiple IDs with the same value. Use class instead

So:

```
<table><tr><td><a class="x">X</a></td></tr></table>
```

And then you can easy hide them by using:

```
$('a:not(.x)').closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: Same question to you, what if the anchor contains a table? Just to make your life harder =P

Answer (score -1):

or you can travel through DOM, .closest();

```
$("#x"). closest('tr').hide(); // this will hide the entire row
```

Comment: What if the anchor contains a table? Haha =P The OP wants to hide the row without the a#x.

Answer (score -2):

I found solution

HTML

```
 <table border="1" style="border:1px solid #FFCC00;color:#000000;width:100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td><a id="x">Table Cell 11</a></td>
    <td><a id="x">Table Cell 12 </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a id="y">Table Cell 21 </a></td>
    <td><a id="x">Table Cell 22</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
 </table>
 <br>
 <button id="button">Hide all a tag with id=x</button>
```

JS

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e){
  // $('a#x').html($('a#x').text(' '));
   $("a#x").hide();
 //console.log('onClick func');    
})
```

[**HERE IS THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RMNJG/17/)

Comment: I didn't read carefully .. about hide rows .. is more easy .. But I see you already have a lot of solution ..